# .CSHTML pages will not render

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am trying to get my server to run .cshtml files. Using WebMatrix 3 I can view the pages by right clicking and selecting "view in browser", but that views through a localmachine port. If I try to access the pages from the internet, I get a 500 error.

Here is what I have done:

- I made sure that MVC 3 was installed (but I keep reading that MVC is not needed for .cshtml... I made sure anywway.
- I did the whole "revert to parent" / "revert to inherited" thing, which is found in many blogs.
- I was getting a 404 error for a while, so I added a MIME type of "text/html" to .cshtml extension. That solved that problem, but only led to my 500 error.

I am suspecting it's something to do with my web.config file because if I remove the file, the page will show, but it reads like text. 
For example (in the most basic page I could think of):

```
@{
   var currentTime = dateTime.Now; 
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Testing</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        The current time is @currentTime .
    </body>
</html>
```

The page will render like:

`@{ var currentTime = dateTime.Now;}` The current time is `@currentTime` .

Yet, I am clueless as to what should or should not be in the web.config file. I have been wracking my brain over this for close to a month...

Here is what is in the web.config file:

```
<configuration>     

    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            <add invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" name="Microsoft® SQL Server® Compact 4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webPages:Version" value="2.0"/>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are writing URL?

Comment: http://www.apolymoxic.com/cooking/index.cshtml --- 

I do not plan to continue using .cshtml files, but I want to fix this issue. I originally started using .aspx, but was having the same issue. I changed to .cshtml after getting WebMatrix, but it, obvious, did not help my dilemma. So, I am hoping that correcting the .cshtml files will help solve my .aspx problem.

Comment: So I changed the defaultAppPool .NET framework to v4.0 and I couldn't see the page at all. No matter what I did, I would always get a 404 error. I ended up changing it back to v2.0 and I am able to see the page but it's only in plain text / html (as the MIME seems to describe). 
I cannot get any razor code to work. Removal of the web.config doesn't help. Removal of the MIME type makes the page render a 404 error. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had an older version... this was answered here:

[CSHTML rendering text only - static page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212351/cshtml-rendering-text-only-static-page/23077458#23077458)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are having problems running this in IIS (Internet Information Services - the built in Web server on Windows). It looks like the directory you are serving is not configured as a Web Application (but it is configured as a Virtual Directory).
To fix this:

1. Open IIS manager (Win + R and copy %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\iis.msc to the run window)
2. Navigate to your directory in the tree on the left (probably \Sites\Default Web Site\something
3. Right click on it and choose "Convert to Application"

These steps should make IIS at least try to render the .cshtml.

On a separate note .cshtml (ie ASP.NET MVC) is so much more easier to learn and understand than .asp (ie simply ASP.NET)

Comment: Thank you, that is definitely a good start - I can now see exactly what the errors are. I have fixed most of them, but now I am back to one of my previous problems - the page renders as pure text.

Comment: Try removing the text/html MIME type from .cshtml again.

Comment: By removing the MIME type, I get a 404 error - it acts like it doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: If you get a 404 then that means that IIS does not know what to do with cshtml files. Setting the MIME will just let it execute as a text file. If by converting it to Application you got it working then at least plain vanilla ASP.NET is working but if cshtml-s are not found then ASP.NET MVC is missing. What MVC version are you using? And contrary to what you read ASP.NET MVC is necessary to render cshtml.

Comment: I have MVC 3 installed - is that what you mean? If there is a specific MVC that I am supposed to be using, can you tell me how I would find out if I have it installed. Using the Installer, it just says that MVC 3 is installed.

Comment: I am grasping at straws here already. The only thing I can think of is for you to run aspnet_regiis to re-register asp.net in IIS. If you have 32-bit system run this: %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir if you have 64-bit system run this: %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

Comment: I did that as well. Then I went and made sure that the mapping was correct. 

I do appreciate all your help. I may just have to start the server from scratch and see if I can get it to work that way. Or, maybe this will just give me an excuse to build a new one. =)