# CSHTML rendering text only - static page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is a continuation of my previous question ([.CSHTML pages will not render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193735/cshtml-pages-will-not-render)), but I am no longer getting a 500 error, thus the new post. My pages are now just rendering plain text / html (regardless of what I do).

I can get the pages to work correctly if I try to view them through WebMatrix3, but I cannot view them from the browser (either localhost or through the web).

I recently realized that my pages were set up for ASP.NET v2.0, which I am guessing does not support .cshtml. So, I changed everything to v4.0 but I still don't have any luck view the pages correctly. It's just plain text.

I have:

- MVC 3 installed
- IIS 7.5 on Win7 Home Premium
- The dir of the pages that I want to load converted to application
- web.config functioning, though I am not sure what else, if anything I need to have it in
- My server functioning normally with HTML, .css, .php, python, etc... But I am having horrible luck with any ASP.NET functionality (this includes .aspx).

I really don't know what other information I need to put here, but if you ask for it, I shall provide it.

**EDIT 1**:
Now I am just getting 404 errors on any .cshtml page I try to view. This happened before when I didn't have the MIME types in, but was corrected (to at least plain text) when I entered the MIME type in. I have no idea what is going on... at this point I am almost ready to just uninstall everything and try to start over. =\

**EDIT 2**:
Okay, so I have gotten rid of my 404 and 500 errors. I ended up adding a privileged user to the application pool (advanced settings > process model > Identity). It was set as defaultAppPool before. Now I am getting this:

```
Type 'ASP._Page_default2_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Type 'ASP._Page_default2_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[HttpException (0x80004005): Type 'ASP._Page_default2_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.]
   System.Web.UI.Util.CheckAssignableType(Type baseType, Type type) +9633480
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +66
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType) +28
   System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.CreateInstanceOfType(String virtualPath) +203
   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryExtensions.CreateInstance(IVirtualPathFactory factory, String virtualPath) +145
   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.CreateInstanceOfType(String virtualPath) +153
   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryExtensions.CreateInstance(IVirtualPathFactory factory, String virtualPath) +73
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath, IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory) +23
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.DoPostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +349
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +89
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Any more ideas? Oh, and creating a new application didn't help, but it was a good idea.

Comment: Did you check the .NET version also on your IIS website/application settings?

Comment: The website, and the application are both set up to use ASP.NET 4.0. I read somewhere that the .dll files needed to be in the bin directory, but I am not sure where the bin directory should be. I created one in the sites root directory, but I can't say that it's helped.

Comment: Do I need to do anything with the .NET users?

Comment: @ScottCarrington the bin needs to be in the root of the site. /bin/*.dll - is there a web.config in the root as well? (sorry, just noticed you have in your description).  How are you browsing to the site? /foo/bar/?

Comment: yes, there is a web.config in the root dir. 
To navigate to the site, I am using either localhost:8080/dir (which generally gives me better error messages), or I can go through the web (http://www.apolymoxic.com/default.cshtml).

Comment: make a new mvc4 application and copy everything over

Comment: Make sure the Managed Pipeline Mode for the application pool for the site in IIS is set to _Integrated_.

Comment: @MikeBrind, the application pool is set to integrated. Actually, I think all the pools that I have (and there aren't very many) are set to integrated. Maybe not the classic, but I am not using that.

Comment: If anyone wants to look at it, it's up... not working, but you can surely view the error. LoL. (http://www.apolymoxic.com/default2.cshtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that an older version of System.Web.WebPages.dll is loaded to memory, and it tries to cast the your cshtml page to a version of WebPages class from that dll.

To test this, try to see what http modules are currently registered:

```
var allModules = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules;
for( int i = 0; i < allModules.Count; i++ ) {
    Trace(allModules.GetKey(i));
}
```

In my case that was:

```
....
__DynamicModule_System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_bca8e05a-5746-45b0-be95-2b920b455ccf

__DynamicModule_System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_c1a67b42-31a9-47f1-8483-9e712fabe2a7
```

To fix the problem you need to replace the older version of System.Web.WebPages.dll in your /Bin folders, or some other dlls that might be referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try explicitly setting the ContentType in the action:

```
public ActionResult NotFound() {
Response.ContentType = "text/html";
return View(); }
```